# Using pattern properties with additionalProperties: false

Tags: raml, mulesoft

I have the requirement to specify an API in raml where the object properties have to be specified otherwise the validation should fail. This is achieved by `additionalProperties: false`.

In addition I would like to specify that the request objects can contain pattern properties, similaryl to the official example:

```
/^note\d+$/?: # restrict any properties whose keys start with "note"
              # followed by a string of one or more digits
        type: string
```

Those two things are ok alone, but when brought together they do not work anymore (as specified in the RAML spec):

```
Moreover, if additionalProperties is false (explicitly or by inheritance) in a given type definition, then explicitly setting pattern properties in that definition is not allowed. If additionalProperties is true (or omitted) in a given type definition, then pattern properties are allowed and further restrict the additional properties allowed in that type.
```

So the question is how can I achieve this requirement. something like:

```
types:
  Person:
    description: |-
      Document representing a person.
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      firstName?:
        description: |-
          The person's first name
        type: string
      /^person_info_.+$/?:
        description: Additional person info.
        type: string
```

Please note that this example will fail saying something like

```
extraneous key [person_info_1] is not permitted
```

Comment: Where are you seeing the error 'extraneous key...'? More context of the error message could be useful.

Comment: thanks for the answer, 

I use the raml in an mulesoft application. The error occurs when "additionalProperties: false" is set and the pattern property  "/^person_info_.+$/?:" is passed. In my case the property in the request is person_info_1

Comment: Please add some lines from the log around the error if it is printed there. Also the versions used of Mule Runtime, APIKit, Studio.

Comment: Log entry:

Message : extraneous key [person_info_1] is not permitted  Location:   Position: Line 0,  Column 0
Error type  : APIKIT:BAD_REQUEST
Element               : xxx-xxx-api-v1-main/processors/0 @ xxxapp:xxx-api-v1.xml:59
Element XML           : <apikit:router config-ref="xxx-api-v1-config"></apikit:router>

Anypoint Studio: 7.3.5

Apikit:
<artifactId>mule-apikit-module</artifactId>
<version>1.3.6</version>
Mule Runtime:
           <app.runtime>4.2.1</app.runtime>

Would you have expected the combination of additionalProperties: false and pattern properties to work?

Comment: No, I just asked because the information of the question was incomplete. Note that the guidelines for question recommend to provide details.

Answer (score 0):

The way I read the RAML specification, it is saying that there are 3 levels of strictness when validating against the properties:

1. additionalProperties=false: The only allowed properties are the ones declared by the type.
2. additionalProperties=true AND pattern properties specified : Any additional property name is valid, but IF the name matches the pattern for a pattern property THEN the value must match the value specification for that pattern property.
3. additionalProperties=true AND no pattern properties specified : Any additional property is valid.

I'm happy to be corrected on the meaning of 2, but that's how the specification seems to read.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So you would say that point 1 is declaring that no pattern properties should exist because they are not explicitly and fully specified?

Comment: Exactly. I think you need additionalProperties=true in order to use pattern properties.

Comment: hmm, I think my use case to fail validation of all undeclared properties and to have a pattern property declared is kind of impossible for the current raml specification.